# responsive text+images in one line irrespective of the screen display size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to align text and banners in one line irrespective of the screen size. Please check the fiddle given below.
If I resize the result window and make it maximum big horizontally, the text and banners are in one line, like I want it.
But when I shrink the result window and make it small, I still need text and banners in one line, which is not happening.

On a desktop monitor I see text + all 3 banners in one line and I want the same display on mobile device, where all 3 banners should shrink with same height.
(The width of all three banners are different but all heights are the same: 60px.)

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moudzdj5/3/**

```
<div id="tophead">
    <div id="mainhead">
        some text
    </div>

    <div id="banners">
        <img src="http://www.bingobugle.com/images/ex234x60.gif">
        <img src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.crossingstv.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/120x60.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should really choose a different `id` for `adhead`. It appears Google automatically sets `display` to `none` on that, together with a whole bunch of other ad-related selectors.

Comment: I use AdBlock btw, probably has something to do with it. Still, for the question's sake it's better to use a different ID here, so people can see the full fiddle.

Comment: I've updated your answer for it (if the update gets accepted)

Comment: Thank you. But I dont see the desired output. when i reduce the result window in the fiddle, I see only 468x60 banners getting reduced. Both takes the size of 234x60 banner and then all 3 banners are reduced. I want all three banners reducing their size proportionally having the height same so that while reducing the result window all three banners are seen in one line. For example, on full screen if it displays "Some text 234x60 468x60 468x60" then in half screen it should look like "some text 117x30 234x30 234x30" and in quarter screen it should look like "some text 58x15 117x15 117x15"

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't an answer, just a comment and edit to your question to make sure that everybody can actually test the fiddle (I said "answer" instead of "question" in my previous comment, that was a typo, sorry)

Comment: oh! i got confused. Thanks for the correction. I am still struggling to get an answer to this. Someone please help... Thank you

Comment: Are you willing to use JavaScript? Because that would make it a lot easier. (And maybe it's even the only way.. but I was really hoping for a CSS answer from someone else, that's why I haven't created an answer yet.)

Comment: If you are referring to the exact calculation that I mentioned for full screen, half screen and quarter screen then I would not be so happy. If Javascript can give me proportionate image reduction then it should be fine. I am waiting for a solution too as I am still hunting for resources on the Internet that matches my question. By proportionate image reduction I mean different screen sizes and not fixed (full/half/quarter) sizes. Thank you.

Comment: I think I found something! Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CSS Solution:

I found a CSS solution, provided that you know the width of all banners.

```css
#tophead {
  width: 100%;
}

#mainhead {
  width: 15%;
}

#ads {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 80%;
}
#ads img {height:auto;}
#ads img#ad1 {width: calc(95% * (234/1170));} /*(adWidth / totalSumWidth)*/
#ads img#ad2 {width: calc(95% * (468/1170));} /*(adWidth / totalSumWidth)*/
#ads img#ad3 {width: calc(95% * (468/1170));} /*(adWidth / totalSumWidth)*/
```

```html
<div id="tophead">
  <div id="mainhead">
    some text
  </div>

  <div id="ads">
    <img id="ad1" src="http://www.bingobugle.com/images/ex234x60.gif" />
    <img id="ad2" src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg" />
    <img id="ad3" src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nw4f7uh7/**)

This uses CSS' `calc()` to calculate the width of the banners, a CSS feature I didn't even know existed until yesterday:)

```
#ads img#ad1 {width: calc(95% * (234/1170));}
```

- Between the `calc(...)` you can perform simple calculations using `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`, where you can mix units like `%`, `px`, `em`, etc.
- The above line makes the with of the banner `95%` of its parent's total width, multiplied by `(234/1170)` (*its_own_width / total_width_of_all_banners*). So basically, it's percentage of the total combined width. This is why you need to know the exact width of all involved banners, for this to work.
- You need to give all the banners a unique ID in the HTML, because they will all need their own CSS-width-rule (`#ad1`, `#ad2`, `#ad3`).
- I used `95%`. In theory this could be `100%`, but there is some space/margin between the banners that I can't find the origin of, causing the last banner to get pushed to the next line. With `98%` they already line up next to eachother, but when you make the window smaller, the last one gets pushed again. `95%` seems a safe bet.
- If you don't like the space/margin between the last banner and the right window side that this creates, you can add `float:right;` to the `#ads img{}` block. But beware that the banners are mirrored now; the left banner is on the right. So you should flip that around in your HTML as well.
- This **will not work on IE8 and below**, and there is **almost no support on mobile platforms**.

---

### JS Solution:

If you want it to work without knowing the exact width of every banner, you need JavaScript.

*(Also, the CSS solution seems to have multi-platform issues, like on mobile browsers... The JavaScript solution should be more consistent.)*

```js
window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {
  //get a nodeList of all banners
  var banners = document.getElementsByClassName("banner");
  //store total width of all banners together
  var totalBannerWidth = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<banners.length; i++) {
    totalBannerWidth += banners[i].naturalWidth;
  }
  //set new width of each banner
  var containerWidth = document.getElementById("ads").offsetWidth;
  for (var j=0; j<banners.length; j++) {
    banners[j].style.width = 0.95*containerWidth * (banners[j].naturalWidth/totalBannerWidth) +"px";
  }
}
```

```css
#tophead {width: 100%;}
#mainhead {width: 15%;}

#ads {
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 0px;
}
#ads img {width:auto; height:auto;}
```

```html
<div id="tophead">
  <div id="mainhead">some text</div>

  <div id="ads">
    <img class="banner" src="http://www.bingobugle.com/images/ex234x60.gif" />
    <img class="banner" src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg" />
    <img class="banner" src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nw4f7uh7/2/**

- The JavaScript code performs the same calculation as the CSS' `calc()`, except it dynamically retrieves the original widths of all banners, and uses those values to scale the banners. This way, you don't have to type in the widths manually, like in CSS.
- Now there are no individual ID's for each banner, only a shared classname.
- This is pure *JavaScript*, no *jQuery*. But **this version will not work on IE8 and below**. For better cross-browser compatibility, translate the code to *jQuery*.

Comment: Wow! thats a gr8 solution. I took me some time to understand. I am going to try this with five banners of different size to see if I understood this approach. Just a question... By 95% of its parent's total width, do you mean "width: 80%;" of "#ads"?

Comment: @user3549869 - yep, 95% of the `#ads`'s `width:80%;`

Comment: Hey thanx.. You made my day.. I understood the solution and tried it with 5 banners (see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/13tLg6yw/). I works perfectly on my 1920x1080 pixels monitor. However, I have a question. When I see this on my mobile screen, it shows me first 3 banners in one line and the other two underneath them (portrait or landscape irrespective) Any idea why it is not resizing automatically on mobile screen and show all 5 banners in one line?

Comment: @user3549869 - Yeah, that's that glitch I'm talking about in the answer, the whole reason why I'm using `95%` instead of `100%`. As an experiment, try using `75%` or even less, to see if the problem remains. If they do all line up with 75% or less, then that's definitely the problem. Let me know. I'll try to find a solution, and otherwise I'll update my answer with a JavaScript example.

Comment: Well I thought so and I had tried that already with 65%.. it shrinks on my desktop screen but no change on mobile :(

Comment: @user3549869 - I added the JavaScript example (under *JS Solution*)